# Bypass htpasswd authentication for url with index.php and without it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have added htpasswd protection using htaccess file for authentication, now I want to bypass authenitcation for `www.website.com` and `www.website.com/index.php` where both urls are accessing index.php file. By using below htaccess file I have allowed index.php and I'm able to bypass `www.website.com/index.php` url but not `www.website.com`

My htaccess file is:

```
# set an environtment variable "noauth" if the request starts with "/callbacks/"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/index.php noauth=1

AuthType Basic

AuthName "RESTRICTED"
#AuthName "Restricted Area"

AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"

require valid-user

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /file.php?show=all&name=$1 [L]

# Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the 2nd parameter just uses regular regex. Maybe you can just make index.php optional.

```
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(index\.php)?$" noauth=1
```

Have not tested.

Comment: Yeah it worked but there is something different going on with this one as well as with my previous code. When I open www.website.com or www.website.com/index.php it keeps on asking for username and password, although it was working fine for url with index.php yesterday, when I click on cancel instead of displaying Authorization Required (401) its displaying content from index.php with 401 error for style/images/js folder inside firebug console. That means its allowing to display content from index.php page but why is it asking for username and password on this page.

Comment: ^^^ it might be because its denying access from style/css/images/js folders, but how to overcome such thing. How to achieve what I require.

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for, and its showing authentication popup because of other folders that are disallowed. I just allowed those folders as well and its working now.